# Magento Tables and EAV

Tags: magento

Are all the tables in Magento follow EAV Design ?

Where can I find information about tables, I mean what each table does and what is it storing etc ?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All tables that have flat in the name are set up as standard relational DB files.

A good site to use for tracking all the tables and worrying out their relations is [the MAGEREVERSE online Database Diagram Tool](http://www.magereverse.com/)

Comment: You're welcome. It even has the **Structure Dump** link for each version listed. This is supposed to be a full list of SQL commands necessary to create a complete blank database for that version and came in handy for troubleshooting a problem I had in an upgrade when it failed to add certain columns to one of the tables.

Comment: Good link that will help lots of developer who do customization.

Answer (score 3):

Only tables related to Catalog (category/product), Customers follow EAV structure.
 
Before Magento 1.4 Orders used to have EAV structure but now they have flat structure. 
Thanks

Comment: why catalog as both flat and eav?

Comment: How it minimize performance issue with 2 different kind of table structure logic?

Comment: If you switch to Flat structure mode from  Admin Panel -> System -> Configuration -> Frontend and select "Yes" against "Use Flat Catalog Product" and Re-Index, you can note the significant difference in page load (frontend). Can you gtmetrix.com or yslow plugin for firefox for testing purpose.

Comment: Yes, i use magento from 1y i know that, so EAV catalog is completely useless!

Comment: Nope. Flat table fields are even based on the EAV attributes.Without EAV Flat table has no existence.

Comment: you are right! Flat catalog table is created on the base of EAV catalog table :)